# Allowing normal users to download PloneFormGen CSV

Tags: csv, plone, ploneformgen

We are using PloneFormGen's SaveDataAdapter, and would like users who are not site admins to be able to download the CSV. The normal permissions don't seem to allow this. Is this possible in PloneFormGen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there is a custom permission made for the `download`-view named "PloneFormGen: Download Saved Input", and `Products/PloneFormGen/config.py` defines that Managers, Owners and Site-admins get this permission by default.

In one of your add-on's profile-folder add a file named `rolemap.xml` to additionally assign roles (the default-roles will remain untouched, as they are assigned via a Python-script, not a GenericSetup-file):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rolemap>
  <permissions>
    <permission name="PloneFormGen: Download Saved Input" acquire="True">
      <role name="Member" />
    </permission>
  </permissions>
</rolemap>
```

Note: This will set the permission globally, meaning you cannot restrict it to locations. For finer control per location, create a role "Downloaders", assign the download-permission to it in `rolemap.xml` and make the permission assignable locally via the sharing-tab of an item. For the last step one could give https://pypi.org/project/collective.sharingroles/ a try.

---

An **alternative solution** for the case that exactly one user needs to get the additional privilege for downloading the content of a save-adapter:

Append `/ownership_form` to the URL of the save adapter, choose new owner and save.

Comment: Am currently seeing whether making a user the owner lets them get at it...

Comment: Worked for me. Updated answer with your suggestion.